# Remove the dot of doxygen's \copydoc?

Tags: c++, c, doxygen

I have a problem with doxygen's `\copydoc`. Example

file1.h

```
/*!
 * \file
 * FileOne
 */
```

file2.h

```
/*!
 * \file
 * This is similar to the \copydoc file1.h file.
 */
```

Documentation always says:

> This is similar to the.
>
> FileOne. file.

I don't want this dot (and newline) added. How can i remove it?

The reason is, i want it to read a groupname from that file. If it adds a dot, the group is not found. New Example:

file1.h

```
/*!
 * \defgroup FileOne
 */
/*!
 * \file
 * FileOne
 */
```

file2.h

```
/*!
 * \file
 * \ingroup \copydoc file1.h
 */
```

Documentation always says:

> \ .

The file is not added to the group, because it enters `FileOne.` to the `\ingroup` command.

Answer (score 0):

This is not what `\copydoc` is for. You're trying to use it to substitute a "name" for a file, but what you're actually doing is substituting the *documentation* for a file, which is a paragraph.

I think you should just name the file — with the correct settings, [Doxygen will auto-generate a link to that file's documentation](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/autolink.html#linkfile).

```
/*!
 * \file
 * This is similar to the file1.h file.
 */
```

Comment: I am aware, that i am using `\copydoc` for a case it is not made for. See my second example for the problem.

Comment: @kuga Yeah you're still trying to do something that should not be done. Documentation paragraphs are not substitutable variables. Write `\ingroup FileOne`.

Comment: Well is there a way to do it with doxgen variables. Like define the name in file1.h and use it in file2.h? I dont think there are variables, are there?

Comment: @kuga No I don't believe so and your requirement seems strange to me. Why would you say "this file is in the same group as some other file" instead of "this file is in the group G"?

Comment: I put up a [follow up question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29079666/doxygen-group-hierarchy-automaticly-add-to-base-group) for this

Comment: @kuga That's a much better question ;p