# doxygen - group hierarchy - automaticly add to base group?

Tags: doxygen

You can create a group hierarchy in doxygen:

```
/*!
 * \defgroup Base
 */

/*!
 * \ingroup Base
 * \defgroup Sub1
 * \defgroup Sub2
 */
```

This will be shown as

> - Base
>
>   - Sub1
>   - Sub2

Now if i add something to a subgroup `\ingroup Sub1` it is added to subgroup. How can i add it to `Base` as well without doing it manually? How can i find out in which group `Sub1` is?

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29073602/remove-the-dot-of-doxygens-copydoc) approach but it failed.

Comment: I don't know much about Doxygen groups, so here's a non-prejudiced, honest question: when you add something to a subgroup doesn't that implicitly mean it's part of the base group as well? If so you would not need to add it to both `Sub1` and `Base` — membership of the former implies membership of the latter. That's how I'd typically understand a membership _hierarchy_, at least.

Comment: @ Lightness: That is what is think to. but if i click on the module Base it does not show the files added to Sub1 or Sub2. And i would want to see all member of Base, Sub1 and Sub2, because they are all Base in my opinion. Since they are not added, i have to click through all subgroups and that might be a lot with maybe only one file.

Comment: That sounds more like an adjustment that should be made to Doxygen's rendered output (perhaps a "flatten" mode?), rather than something that should drive your choice of memberships in the first place.